# how to make the last version of my app is the only working version in android

Tags: android, google-play, version, android-install-apk, google-play-console

I have uploaded my app on google play store. I need when I do an update in my app the old versions of the app doesn't work on user devices until they updated the app. For example when I make an update when the users that have old versions of the app opens it a dialog opens to them asking them to update the app to be able to use it , How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go and change old versions retrospectively - the code is already out there on devices.

If you want this feature in new versions of your app however, I would recommend using something like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/). That will let you control the minimum version of your app on a server, so you could give the users a week to update, then change the config on the server, and the app will know to ask the user to update.